# Arguments validation in factory constructor?

Tags: validation, oop, design-patterns, constructor, factory-pattern

Good day. I hope you can help me.

Let's say, I have a *class*. Its constructor has some parameters. Inside the constructor, one or more values passed as arguments at the instantiation time are validated. If one of them is not valid, an exception is thrown.

I also have a *factory* class, whos factory method should create an object of the above type. The factory constructor has some of the parameters defined in the class above. The other parameters, needed for creating the object, are defined in the factory method.

I would like to ask: Should the arguments passed to the factory constructor be validated too - in an identical manner as in the class constructor?

Thank you for your time and patience. Feel free to ask me anything.

---

I also prepared an example (in PHP). In regard to it, should a `validateColor` method be defined in the `HatFactory` too, although the identical validation already happens in the `Hat` class?

#### test.php

```
<?php

use Tests\HatFactory;

$hatFactory = new HatFactory('yellow');

$hat1 = $hatFactory->createHat('AdiDix');

$hat2 = $hatFactory->createHat('NiKy');

echo '<pre>' . print_r($hat1, TRUE) . '</pre>';

echo '<pre>' . print_r($hat2, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

#### Tests/Hat

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

class Hat {

    /**
     * Hat brand.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * Hat color.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @param string $brand Hat brand.
     * @param string $color Hat color.
     */
    public function __construct(string $brand, string $color) {
        $this->validateColor($color);

        $this->brand = $brand;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the hat color.
     *
     * @param string $color Hat color.
     * @throws Exception Color not allowed.
     */
    private function validateColor(string $color) {
        if ($color !== 'red' && $color !== 'blue') {
            throw new Exception('The selected color is not allowed!');
        }
    }

}
```

#### Tests/HatFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Tests\Hat;

class HatFactory {

    /**
     * Hat color.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @param string $color Hat color.
     */
    public function __construct(string $color) {
        $this->validateColor($color);

        $this->color = $color;
    }

    /**
     * Create a hat.
     *
     * @param string $brand Hat brand.
     */
    public function createHat(string $brand) {
        return new Hat($brand, $this->color);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the hat colour.
     *
     * @param string $color Hat color.
     * @throws \Exception Color not allowed.
     */
    private function validateColor(string $color) {
        if ($color !== 'red' && $color !== 'blue') {
            throw new \Exception('The selected color is not allowed!');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, taking into account your implementation of the factory -where the color is also a constructor argument- you should add validation as well, because the color is a property of the factory itself, and the factory shouldn't exist in an invalid state...

Think that, right now, the `$color` property is only used in the `createHat` method, which creates a `Hat` object, but there's nothing that prevents that in the future that property might be used for something else as well... maybe you add a `createTopHat` method that creates a `TopHat` that doesn't have validation in the constructor... or maybe you want to add a `getColor` method in order to organize your factories by color... or anything you can imagine!

If the color was an argument of the `createHat` method itself, then you should probably avoid the duplicate validation, but as long as the factory requires a valid color to exist, it should be validated...

That said, assuming the validation of the color is always the same for the `Hat` and the `HatFactory` (which seems to be *now*, but doesn't need to be!), you could move that to some `ColorValidator` class to keep DRY - that'd be a good idea imo

Comment: Hi, MikO, and thanks for an interesting answer. Until your last phrase, by reading it, I suddently thought: _Oh, I shouldn't introduce a validation in the factory at all. Let's say, indeed, I have two factory methods: `createHat` and `createTopHat`. And let's say `Hat` and `TopHat` are related by a parent `Accessoires`, but they have distinct validation methods (even though, maybe, with the same name). Now, if a `Hat` is valid only when its color argument is 'red' or 'blue', but a `TopHat` doesn't need a validation at all, or its color argument is valid only if its 'yellow',_

Comment: _then a validation on the color wouldn't make much sense in the factory. Except, maybe in each factory method, for some steps prior to create the corresponding object_. That I said myself :-) Then I read your last phrase and realised that you certainly thought of the case of both classes, `Hat` and `TopHat`, needing a different validation. Based on this idea, would you be so kind to give me your thoughts? Thanks, I appreciate.

Comment: @dakis the point is, if the factory holds the color property for something else apart from forwarding it to the methods, you should add validation to the factory based on the reasons why the factory needs the color. However, if the color property is there _only_ to forward it to the methods, I would just _not_ add it as a property but as a method argument, and leave the validation only in the classes... If you still want to add it as a property anyway, you still need to validate it so it passes validation in _any_ of the hats it can create... hope that helps..

Comment: MikO, great explanations. And it would be great if, in the end, you'll copy/paste them in your answer. Yes, that is the problem: I am forced to add color as class property. So, it has to be read by each factory method and passed to the corresponding new object, as argument.

Comment: In this scenario, since `createHat` creates a `Hat` with only _**red**_ and _**blue**_, but `createTopHat` creates a `TopHat` with only _**yellow**_ as color, then what kind of validation would you suggest in the factory constructor? I personally see only one possibility: to validate against all **three colors**. Though, this seem a bit strange. What do you think?

Comment: I forgot to mention: the factory constructor arguments are just used in the two factory methods.

Comment: @dakis yeah the whole approach seems a bit weird, because according to what you say, the color doesn't belong as a property of the factory at all, but as an argument of the factory's methods... as it's a weird scenario, you may just avoid any validation on the factory and that's it... If you add it, yeah it'd need to validate against the 3 colors - there's no other option

Comment: Hi, MikO. Yes, the scenario seems a bit weird. From it, only the fact that the color is a factory constructor parameter is part of my real problem. The rest is something that I thought it could sometimes appear. Again, thank you for your time. I needed another perspective and I am glad that I have found it. Good luck.